# using verifyPasswordResetCode to verify an email on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently setting up some firebase-auth.

For the recovery password and verification of email process, firebase uses some default pages that the user is redirected to by email, before getting back to my website using the `url` for `continueUrl`.

I would instead like to do the recovery and the confirmation of the email on my end directly.

So I understood the steps for recovery are

1. Go to firebase and change the default URL of the email to point to my domain
2. In the code check for the `oobCode`

```
 useEffect(() => {
   async function verifyToken() {
     try {
       const code = searchParams.get('code');
       if (code) {
         const email = await verifyPasswordResetCode(getAuth(), code);
         form.setFieldValue('email', email);
         form.setFieldValue('oobCode', code);
       }
       throw new Error('Missing oobCode');
     } catch (e) {
       setError(e);
     } finally {
       setVeryifing(false);
     }
   }

   setVeryifing(true);
   verifyToken();
 }, []);
```

3. Confirm the password reset

```
  const submitHandler = useCallback(
    async ({ oobCode, password }: FormType) => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        await confirmPasswordReset(getAuth(), oobCode, password);
        setPasswordChange(true);
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    },
    [setLoading]
  );
```

Ok, now, for email verification there is still an `oobCode` that we need to confirm, but I cant find any information about how to verify it. Should I use `verifyPasswordResetCode` even for this case ? or is there other function that I am missing ? or is it not possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation on custom email action handlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#create_the_email_action_handler_page), use [`applyActionCode`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#applyactioncode).

> 4. Handle email address verification by calling `applyActionCode`. For example:
>
> ```js
> function handleVerifyEmail(auth, actionCode, continueUrl, lang) {
>   // Localize the UI to the selected language as determined by the lang
>   // parameter.
>   // Try to apply the email verification code.
>   applyActionCode(auth, actionCode).then((resp) => {
>     // Email address has been verified.
>
>     // TODO: Display a confirmation message to the user.
>     // You could also provide the user with a link back to the app.
>
>     // TODO: If a continue URL is available, display a button which on
>     // click redirects the user back to the app via continueUrl with
>     // additional state determined from that URL's parameters.
>   }).catch((error) => {
>     // Code is invalid or expired. Ask the user to verify their email address
>     // again.
>   });
> }
> ```

In the above snippet:

- `auth` is an instance of Firebase Auth returned by `getAuth()`.
- `actionCode` is the `oobCode` GET parameter.
- `continueUrl` and `lang` are their respective GET parameters.

You should consider following the documentation and also implementing support for `resetPassword` and `recoverEmail` as appropriate.

**Note:** The full code sample is available on the [Firebase Snippets GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/e74e8fd9591f70007a44c58580ff0f1fcd1c7959/auth-next/custom-email-handler.js). Some methods are psuedo-code and should be updated to support the framework you are using.